# If a dataset has multiple columns all in different formats, what would be the best approach to deal with such data?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

Say, a dataset has columns like length and width which can be float, and it can also have some binary elements (yes/no) or discrete numbers (categories transformed into numbers). What would it be wise to simply use all these as features without having to worry about the formats (or more like the nature of the features)? When doing normalization, can we just normalize the discrete numbers the same way as continuous numbers? I'm really confused on dealing with multiple formats.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you can normalize discrete values. But it ought have no real
   effect on learning - normalization would be required if you are
   doing some form of a similarity measurement, which is not the case
   for factor variables. There are some special cases like neural
   networks, which are sensible to the scale of input\output and the
   size of weights (see 'vanishing\exploding gradient' topic). Also it
   would make some sense if you are doing a clustering on your data.
   Clustering uses some kind of a distance measure so it would be
   better to have all features on the same scale.
2. There is nothing special with categorical stuff, except that some of
   the learning methods are especially good at using categorical
   features, some - at using real-valued features, and some are good at
   both.

My first choice for mix of categorical and real-valued features would be to use some tree-based methods (RandomForest or Gradient Boosting Machine) and the second one - ANNs.

Also, extremely good approach at handling factors (categorical variables) is to convert them into set of Boolean variables. For example if you have a factor with five levels (1,2,3,4 and 5) a good way to go would be to convert it into 5 features with 1 in a column representing one of the levels.

Comment: thanks!I think I'll give random forest a try. I was using K-NNR as a reference (since it doesn't require training, I use it as a base value for my projects most of the time)

Comment: @JChao well, KNNR will have horrible performance if you have smth like 10 inputs (curse of dimensionality - majority of NN will be closer to the bounds than to ANY example, regardless of the input scales). Also if RandomForest won't satisfy you I really suggest to try GBR - it is also tree-based but builds an ensemble of trees in a more smart way and almost always (in my experience) outperforms RandomForest

Comment: I tried KNNR and random forest (using sklearn's ML algo), and the result for KNNR, as expected, is pretty bad (~20% for ~4200 samples, half as training and half as testing). Surprisingly though (at least for me), random forest's performance is pretty much the same as the NNR. Could it be the fact that I have too many classes (28 total) so the problem becomes hard to solve? I did reduce the class size by grouping some classes together (reduced to 7 classes), and the accuracy did go up to ~67%. I do have suspicion, just not sure what is the actual cause here. care to share?

Comment: @JChao, sorry, in earlier you mentioned KNNR which is K-NN regression, while now you are saying '28 classes'. So you are actually trying to do a KNNC - a classifier with 28 classes? If true, than yes, having 28 classes is a rather hard task to to solve without couple of tricks - because roughly you reduce amount of data you have to distinguish each class from other classes by the amount of classes you have.

Comment: @JChao roughly speaking, consider you have 10000 of training examples, and you train to classify them into 5 classes. You have 2000 of data ppoints for each class (on average). Now if you try to do the same for 20 classes you will have just 400 of data points for each class, which definitely makes the task harder

Comment: @JChao so if you want to classify that many classes you may want to go for OneVsRest meta-classifier approach. That means you train not one but 28 classifiers, one for each class. Each of them should be a binary classifier  which should just output 1 or 0 (and a confidence or probability) for each of classes. Read about OneVsRest classification approach and try it. Also - try Gradient Boosting Machine, it is available in sklearn and might work much better.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help! I'll give one v all a try and see what the result looks like. Do you know if I can also play around with the attributes to reduce the number of columns for training (something like PCA? does it help?)

Comment: Also, I tried GBR without really tweaking the parameters (simply buld, fit, then score). Interestingly, when I test it on the 28-class dataset, the result is 54.1%, but when I tried it on the 7-class dataset after the operation I mentioned above, the result dropped to 49.7%. Im wondering why this would happen. Intuitively I would think it's harder to classify more classes.

Comment: and sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to build a classifier for now. Regressor will probably come later, which I might start a new discussion thread :)

Comment: @JChao well, now we are getting on the territory of a pure data science, which means you need to play with this stuff for a while. Try PCA or some other dimensionality reduction methods. Try feature engineering to improve the performance, etc. You could also try to drop out the features which are not significant for result - which is simple for RandomForest and GBM since both of these classifiers output the feature importance and you could remove features with low importance.

Comment: @JChao as for the performance decrease which happened when you shrink the number of classes - most likely reason is that GBC is rather smart and powerful and was able to capture how to split 28 classes from each other. But when you merged some classes it became hard for it to distinguish some of merged classes from each other (they became closer to each other in the feature space in which GBM works - so sometimes decreasing number of classes actually makes it harder to separate classes from each other).

Comment: Thanks! You're being really helpful!